# How to create wsdl file for android SOAP operations?

Tags: android, web-services

While implementing SOAP webservice accessing, i found there is a wsdl file in some tutorials. In which folder i have to create wsdl file when there is no third party libraries adding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the WSDL file of the deployed service by requesting the URL

for example,

```
http://localhost:8080/helloservice/hello?wsdl
```

so basically

```
http://<your-web-service-url>?wsdl
```

should work